# Creating a new File instance with a parent directory returns a File inside the root instead of the parent

Tags: java, file

I have this method to get the directory that my Java program is running inside.

```
public File getWorkingDir() {
    Path path = Paths.get("");
    
    return path.toFile(); // Returns "D:\users\Simon\myprogram"
}
```

But when I create a new `File` instance with this directory as its parent, it returns a `File` inside the drive's root.

```
File file = new File(getWorkingDir(), "testfile");
```

I was expecting the absolute path of this file to be `D:\users\Simon\myprogram\testfile`, but instead its `D:\testfile`.

Comment: Have you consider just using `Path`, instead of switching to `File`?

Comment: What about getAbsolutePath()?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Well, I need the `File` object later in my program, so I need to convert it to a File eventually

Comment: @RichardKYu What do you mean?

Comment: I was thinking of this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsoluteFile() . You want to create file in project folder and not root right? I may have misinterpreted what the issue is though.. the path itself is appearing in the root?

Comment: @RichardKYu That helped me solve the problem, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Paths.get` is not returning what you expect. The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#of(java.lang.String,java.lang.String...)) says this about its parameters:

> A Path representing an empty path is returned if first is the empty string and more does not contain any non-empty strings.

An empty path must be resolved in order to pin its location within the file system. Resolving behaves differently across the `File` class. The method `File.getAbsolutePath`, for example, resolves the empty path against the current working directory. The constructor `File(File, String)` resolves an empty parent against the system's default directory.

You could probably get the desired outcome by resolving the parent directory explicitly:

```
public String getWorkingDir() {
    Path path = Paths.get("");
    
    return path.toFile().getAbsolutePath(); // Returns "D:\users\Simon\myprogram"
}
```

However, the current working directory is directly available as a property:

```
String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
```